# Difference between Operator * and operator @ for matrix multiplication in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to compute matrix multiplication in the mathematical sense with Python. A matrix with `m` rows and `n` columns multiplied by a matrix with `n` rows and `m` columns gives a matrix with `m` rows and `m` columns. I used the operator `*` incorrectly at first and got unexpected results. I later learned that the operator `@` is what I need. So what is the difference between these two operators for matrix operations in Python?

Answer (score 0):

`*` is an element wise multiplication and `@` is a matrix or dot product.

Answer (score 0):

- The `*` operator is equivalent to the [`multiply`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html#numpy.multiply) function (in terms of array broadcasting).
- The `@` operator is equivalent to the [`matmul`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html#numpy.matmul) function (the `matmul` function implements the semantics of the @ operator introduced in Python 3.5 following PEP 465)